# Simple Client-Server Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, wcf, client-server

Has the following architecture: the client part(dll on C#) sends a certain number of images on a server(or Windows Service or Web Service), where they are processed and then server sends back a response in the form of XML file of processing results.

The client is simply an automated app with no interface and input / output.

Server. It turns the engine using multithreading (using ThreadPool) to process the images. Accordingly, when refers a new client, the server creates a new thread in which processing occurs, at the end it sends a reply to the user(xml file). The load on the server is not very big 3-20 concurrent connections.

So far, I can't understand what is the architecture of interaction is best suited for my case. There are several ways to implement, or to write an asynchronous sockets server on, either use WCF or just write ASP.NET application and pour it on IIS(for this option I'm leaning most).

Which transfer Protocol is the best to use? Do HTTP for transferring large amounts of pictures(then you can move in the direction Web Service), or should think about TCP/IP(now WCF)?

That's all!

Comment: who is the end user? is that an individual on web or its an application? What is the throughput requirement?

Comment: hire a technical/solutions architect.

Comment: Look into Streaming with WCF - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733742(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: In this scenerio a web service application is easier to implement. TCP service application will require a transfer protocol implementation, and usually needs a windows service application also.

Comment: Thanks for replays. The end user is an appication, so no interface is needed. Еhe bandwidth requirements are quite low, at the same time will be around 10-20 connections. So, as I understand, I should use WCF or ASP.NET

Answer (score -1):

Here is a way to send them individually:

```
        Byte[] imgByte = null;
        System.IO.Stream strm;
        string imgfile = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.FileName);
        string ext = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.FileName);
        if (ext == ".jpg" | ext == ".jpeg" | ext == ".gif" | ext == ".png")
        {
            try
            {

                if (FileUpload1.HasFile && FileUpload1.PostedFile != null)
                {
                    int fileLen = FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentLength;
                    HttpPostedFile File = FileUpload1.PostedFile;
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    imgByte = new Byte[fileLen];
                    strm = FileUpload1.FileContent;
                    strm.Read(imgByte, 0, fileLen);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Label1.Text = "Stream: " + ex.ToString();
            }
            if (imgByte != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["imgContext"].ConnectionString;
                    string cmdStr = "INSERT INTO [Table] (filename, image) VALUES (@filename, @image);";
                    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr))
                    {
                        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdStr, conn))
                        {
                            conn.Open();
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@filename", imgfile);
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@image", imgByte);
                            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                            conn.Close();
                            cmd.Dispose();
                            conn.Dispose();
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Label2.Text = "sql: " + ex.ToString();
                }
            }
```

Comment: You will want to put your .Close and .Dispose statements in a Finally block, not inside the try block...